# bootstrap collapse panel border

Tags: background-image, panel

On the bootstrap panel header, I replaced background colour to image background which is works great.

And then in around panel header border showing white border and I changed to the transparent border.

But I'm still showing bottom white border on panel header and not sure where this come from.

Does anyone know how can I remove that white bottom white border and show only full image background **WITHOUT AROUND COLOR BORDER!.**

here is code.

```
<style>
.panel-default .panel-heading{
    background-image: url(../images/red-header.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color:white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 13px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border:soiid 1px #BF1D2B;

}
</sylte>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
                    <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    Founded in 1892 and headquartered in Fairfield, CT, LexisNexis Corporate Affiliations 
                    is a technology and financial services company. 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your page, just correcting 'soiid' to 'solid', and your panel-heading border has the color # BF1D2B you have set. So if you remove this property, I think you get what you want. Note: I may not have understood your question very well, sorry.

Comment: even I fixed that I'm still showing the bottom white border.